# Completion object race condition

Tags: linux-kernel

What happens if `complete_all()` is called on a completion object (from *task B*) before the *task A* gets to do `wait_for_completion()` on the completion object? Is there some API to find if object is already completed at time of wait and return right away? One way could be using a `mutex` which is locked before sending the message and unlocked before the wait. That lock needs to be acquired before `complete_all()` and released after but wondering if there is a cleaner/better way. Any ideas are welcome.

**More context:** *task A* initializes the completion object, sends a request to *task B* along with the address of the completion object and then waits for the completion. *Task B* does some processing when it gets the message and then does `complete_all()` on the completion object.

Comment: The kernel already handles this case afair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `complete()` or `complete_all()` is called before `wait_for_completion()` for a particular completion object, then `wait_for_completion()` will return immediately.  A completion object is roughly like a semaphore:

- Internally, a completion object has a `done` counter that is initialized to 0.
- `wait_for_completion()` sleeps until `done > 0` (or proceeds immediately if `done` is already greater than 0), and atomically decrements `done` before returning.
- `complete()` increments `done` and wakes up the first process sleeping in `wait_for_completion()`.
- `complete_all()` sets `done` to `UINT_MAX / 2` (effectively infinity) and wakes up everyone sleeping in `wait_for_completion()`.

So if I'm understanding your question correctly, there is no need for additionaly locking; the completion object's internal `wait.lock` spinlock already synchronizes the counter access so that the case you're worrying about is handled correctly.